# SSIS - Changing references to a Variable/Parameter through all the project

Tags: parameters, ssis, package, etl, find-replace

I've created an SSIS project, thinking it will be deployed in Project Deployment mode.

A Lot of my packages have 2 Parameters (called `P_OdsTbl` and `P_SrcEtl`), and whenever I used Execute package task I bound the Child Parameters to the Parent Parameters.

I've since discovered that the project would be deployed in Package Deployment mode, which means I need to change the Parameters to Variables (`V_OdsTbl` and `V_SrcEtl`) and set their values with Variable Configurations.

I have many references to these two parameters inside the packages and going through all of them to change them manually is both time consuming and unsafe (I might miss some references).

Is there a way to search all the references through the project, or better yet; replace them with references to the new variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TabAlleman mentioned you can use a text editor and replace text in .dtsx files since they are xml based files.

In addition, i will suggest using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which contains a feature that allow user to find and replace in all files in a directory.

For more information check the following link:

- [How to find and replace line(s) in multiple files using Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/1003790/how-to-find-and-replace-lines-in-multiple-files-using-notepad)
- [How to Find and Replace Words in Multiple Files](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text editor to search and replace the text in the .dtsx file.